# How determine child ordinal position? Need: $("#parent").ordinalChild('#some-child') => 3 (say)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

Because Jquery UI tab [doesn't support passing id selector to remove() tab method](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/3171), and [no method exists to map id to index](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4354), I have to painfully "jump hoops" to determine the index of the tab I wish to remove.

I just searched the documentation for JQuery and wasn't able to find a utility method to return an integer of the ordinal position of some child under a parent. I think I want the functional *opposite* of the

```
.eq()
```

traversing method (determine index, not select by index).

Does something like this exist?:

```
$("#parent").ordinalChild('#some-child')
```

This would return 0 if "some-child" is the first child, 1 for the second child, etc.

Or how do I go about obtaining this without writing a loop and counting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

> If a selector string is passed as an argument, `.index()` returns an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to the elements matched by the selector. If the element is not found, `.index()` will return -1.

```
$('#parent').children().index('#some-child');
```

Comment: On the main documenation page I searched each of the categories under "jQuery API Reference" three times and it's not listed! Thanks for pointing that out to me.